# Android: How to Open Activity after Login Activity/Authentication when we click on Push Notification

Tags: android, firebase, notifications

In an app need to open a Notification and show it in an Activity. But in case the user is not logged in, the user must be redirected to Login first then to the Notification Activity.

What is the best way to achieve this?

Any idea or code is appreciable.

Comment: Please show some code show what you've tried so far.

Comment: i have tried pending intent to open specific activity and it is working just fine. But only challenge is Login activity will appear if the user is not logged in or session is null.

Comment: you should go to login activity first , then check if this is a call from notification click and user is logged in.. then go to notification screen.

Comment: @akshay while creating  notification pending intent  check login status with shared preference if true then show notification else  Login , this is straight forward solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess here is the flow of your app when a user click on a notification.

- If the user is logged in, you will open Notification Activity
- If the user is not logged in, you will open Login Activity, after login success then go to Notification Activity.

You have resolved the first case. For the second case, when start Login Activity you should put notification data into `Intent` which start the Login Activity. For example

```
intent.putExtra("notificationData", data); // This intent will be wrapped by your PendingIntent.
```

In Login Activity, after login success, you will check in the intent if there is any `notificationData` or not. Then you will decide the next activity is Notification Activity or another activity (Dashboard or Home Activity for example).

**Login Activity**

```
public void goToNextActivity() {
    Data data = getIntent.getParcelableExtra("notificationData");
    if (data == null) {
        // Go to Dashboard or Home Activity
    } else {
        // Go to Notification Activity
    }
}
```

Comment: it works fine, but i wanted to know is this the right approach.

Comment: This is the simple and easy way to solve your problem. You do not need any third party libraries or use any extra variables. Intent and Bundle are the best way to pass data among components in Android. So this is the right approach. If you find any better approaches, please let me know.

Comment: Yes i have implemented this already, but still i was looking for a different approach. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Feel free to use OneSignal, it handles notifications perfectly for this type of requirements. From Application class, you can override what to do when receiving notification. Also, I would suggest putting the "logged in" state inside some shared preferences, or somewhere where it is easily retrievable. For OneSignal, try to look  [here](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/android-native-sdk#section--notificationopenedhandler-)

Answer (score -1):

Please create a Splash screen, this screen will decide where to go. The logic should be in the splash screen, like if the user is authenticated (already logged in) redirect him to specific screen you want him to go. If user is not authenticated (not logged in) redirect him to login screen and send a flag in intent from notification click to open the splash saying the request came from notification, once the login is successful (you need to send the flag to login activity also from splash screen), you can redirect him to notification activity if the flag is present.

Comment: When clicked on Notification. then do other stuff. He isn't Creating a new application.

Comment: I am not saying to create a new application, from splash he redirects to either login screen or to that particular activity. I cant understand what you are talking about..can you elaborate?

Comment: by default app will open login page if not logged in, also if logged in it will open notification page. But what is the solution for my question.

Comment: Read the updated answer, you can send a flag in intent from notification click to open the splash saying the request came from notification, once the login is successful, you can redirect him to notification activity